# Texture does not work properly

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to put a texture defined in PNG file to a custom made model in defined by OBJ file.

I have this folder structure with the model

```
model_name
├── materials
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── model_name.material
│   └── textures
│       └── floor0.png
├── meshes
│   └── model_name.obj
├── model.config
└── model.sdf
```

this is the image floor0.png

[image: image description]

This is the model.sdf file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <model name="model_name">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model://model_name/meshes/model_name.obj</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
            <friction>
                <ode>
                    <mu>1</mu>
                    <mu2>1</mu2>
                    <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
                    <slip1>0</slip1>
                    <slip2>0</slip2>
                </ode>
            </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>model:/model_name/meshes/model_name.obj</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>model://model_name/materials/scripts</uri>
            <uri>model://model_name/materials/textures</uri>
            <name>Floor0</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

this is the model_name.material file content

```
material Floor0
{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {
            texture_unit
            {
                texture ../textures/floor0.png
                scale 1.0 1.0
            } 
        }
    }
```

And this is the resulting view in Gazebo when I launch spawn this model

[image: image description]

It is only one color (the color in the bottom left corner of the PNG file). Couriously if I change the scale in the material file, the color might change to orange (the color in the middle of the PNG file) but the color stays homogeneous.

What is happening and how do I make the Gazebo render the texture correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23554/texture-does-not-work-properly/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem seems to be on the UV mapping of your OBJ file.

We usually use MTL files to set the material of OBJ meshes, see an example [here](https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/openrobotics/fuel/models/Ambulance). I would try to export an MTL file together with your OBJ from the modelling software you used.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-08-22**:
Thank you! I had to make the UV map for my model inside Blender by hand following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izqZe8s_Jmw) and after that the textures applied to the model are showing correctly.